# The Lebesgue integral of nonnegative function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the following:

If $f ≥ 0$ is measurable with respect to the measure $m$ and 
$\mu_f (\lambda) = m(\{x : f(x) > \lambda\})$ then 
$\int f dm = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu_f (\lambda) d\lambda$ where $d\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

I use the fact that $f(x)= \int_{0}^{f(x)} 1 d\lambda$.
Then I apply Fubini Theorem to switch integrals.

So I have :  $\int_{X} f dm = \int_{X} \int_{0}^{f(x)} 1 d\lambda dm =\int_{0}^{f(x)} \int_{X} 1 dm d\lambda = \int_{0}^{f(x)} m(X) d\lambda $.

How can I replace my upper bound of the integral by infinity?
Thank you

Comment: You did not interchange limit correctly -- the outer limit should not  depend on the dummy of the inner integral.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int fdm&=\int\int_0^\infty 1\{f>\lambda\}d\lambda dm \\
&=\int_0^\infty\int 1\{f>\lambda\}dm d\lambda=\int_0^\infty m(\{f>\lambda\})d\lambda.
\end{align}